# Alternatives to RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android

I was building a scheduling app where you can add tasks to specific days. In my view, I have a ScrollView and inside ScrollView I have TextViews that have names of the days and I also added recycler views for every day of the week that would hold the tasks. But I realized that I don't want the tasks to scroll. I just want them to extend the view. Since the number of tasks will be dependent on user input, I could not find an alternative to the Recycler view. I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have quite the same requirements some times ago. And create library for such tasks. You can check, maybe it will suite you. It's [LinkedListView](https://github.com/GensaGames/Sample-LinkedListView).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView if you don't want another scroll.

Another approach is you can use Custom Layout manager and disable scrolling when your RecylclerView is inside ScrollView

```
public class CustomLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
    private boolean isScrollEnabled = true;

    // orientation should be LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL or HORIZONTAL
    public CustomLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean isScrollEnabled) {
        super(context, orientation, false);
        this.isScrollEnabled = isScrollEnabled;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
        //Similarly you can customize "canScrollHorizontally()" for managing horizontal scroll
        return isScrollEnabled && super.canScrollVertically();
    }
}
```